# Passar array para modal com JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery, array

Fala pessoal, tudo bem? tou com um probleminha aqui que ta tirando meu sono. rs
Eu consigo passar variaveis para o modal tranquilamente como no exemplo a baixo:

Botão que passa a variavel para o modal:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs tooltips" data-placement="top" data-original-title="AlterarBoletos"
data-toggle="modal" 
data-target="#alterarboletoscheckbox" 
data-alt_ndoc="<?php echo $variavel ?>"
><i class="fas fa-magic"></i>
</button>
```

O problema ta quando eu preciso passar informações para o array:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="excluir[]" id="excluir[]" value="<?php $variavel ?>" /> 

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs tooltips" data-placement="top"            data-original-title="Alterar Boletos" 
                                                    data-ndoc_checks="<?php echo $this->input->post('excluir') ?>"
                                                    data-toggle="modal" 
                                                    data-target="#alterarboletoscheckbox" 
                                                    data-alt_ndoc="excluir[]"
                                                    ><i class="fas fa-magic"></i>
                                                </button>
```

JQUERY:

```
$('#alterarboletoscheckbox').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
    var alt_ndoc = button.data('alt_ndoc') // Extract info from data-* attributes

    var modal = $(this)
    
    modal.find('#alt_ndoc').val(alt_ndoc)
    
})
```

O meu resultado é simplesmente ' excluir[] '.
Alguem me da uma luz? Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Fala pessoal. consegui aqui! pode encerrar! :)

```
$('#alterarboletoscheckbox').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var idBoletos = "";
    var qtdBoletos = "";

    $.each($("input[name='excluir']:checked"), function(){
        //PEGANDO O VALOR E COLANDO UMA VIRGULA
        idBoletos += $(this).val()+",";
        qtdBoletos = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
    })
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget) 
    var nomecorretor = button.data('nomecorretor')
    nomecorretor = nomecorretor.substring(0, nomecorretor.indexOf(" ")).toUpperCase();
    var modal = $(this)

    modal.find('#idBoletos').val(idBoletos)
    $(".textoQtd span").text(nomecorretor + ", você está alterando " +qtdBoletos + " boleto(s).")
    
})
```